# Raw sockets in Rust

Tags: sockets, network-programming, rust

I worked with raw sockets in C. I want to do the same in Rust. As far as I know, there is no such low-level functionality in the standard library. How can I make raw socket calls regardless?

Answer (score 5):

If you're ending up here from google, this is now available on rust as a crate called pnet

https://crates.io/crates/pnet

The docs are here:

https://docs.rs/pnet/0.20.0/pnet/

Answer (score 3):

This is something that is [in progress](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/11410).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This *does* provide an answer. The answer is clearly no, it is not stable, but it is being implemented in the standard library.

Comment: This pull request eventually became libpnet https://github.com/libpnet/libpnet